# I'm writing a script so that on entering a specific customer code in column A in Sheet 2 it will match and copy the matching row from Sheet 1

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets

I have a customer details in Sheet 1 with a customer account code for each customer under column A and the corresponding customer name under column B and address under column C.
In sheet 2 I want to start with row 1 column A where I will enter a customer account code which when matches with the customer account code under column A in Sheet 1 will copy the data in the corresponding rows over to sheet 2.
Then again when I enter the row 2 in sheet 2 this will match and copy that corresponding data from sheet 1.

The code I have will work when I enter in Sheet 2 row 1 column A, but I cannot get it to code to work when I proceed to enter data in further rows under column A. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

````
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var docketsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Dockets');
  var customersSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Customers");

  docketsSheet.getRange("A20:I1000").clear();

  var i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++;
  var getLastRow = docketsSheet.getLastRow(); 
  var code = docketsSheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  
 
  var lastRow = customersSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var foundRecord = false;
   
  for(var j = 2; j < lastRow; j++)
  { 
    if(customersSheet.getRange(j,1).getValue() == code)
    {
      var nextRow = docketsSheet.getLastRow() +1;
      var getCopyRange = customersSheet.getRange('A' + j +':F' + j);
      getCopyRange.copyTo(docketsSheet.getRange(nextRow, 2));
      foundRecord = true;

    }
    
    }

    if(foundRecord == false)
    {
      docketsSheet.getRange(5,1).setValue(['no record found']);
    }

}```

I'm very new to coding and will be very grateful of any assistance.
Thanks
````

Comment: Why you clear `docksheet` at beginning?

Comment: I copied the script from a tutorial where it said to clear the sheet to ensure all the cells are empty. It didn't matter because the clear starts from row 20 down. My issue is how to amend the code rather than the search range set to row 1 column A, I need the code so the getValue() range can work in all the cells in column A. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code to update the customer list and write "no found`when the code is not listed, the only difference is that`clearValue()` can be skipped:

```
function updateData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var docketsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Dockets');
  var customersSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Customers");
  var lastCust = customersSheet.getLastRow();
  var cusList = customersSheet.getRange(2,1,lastCust,3).getValues();

  var newCUst = docketsSheet.getLastRow();
  docketsSheet.getRange(newCUst,2).setValue("Not found");
  var code = docketsSheet.getRange(newCUst,1).getValue();

  for (j = 0;j <cusList.length;j++){

      if (cusList[j][0] == code){
        var name = cusList[j][1];
        var address = cusList[j][2];
        docketsSheet.getRange(newCUst,2).setValue(name)
        docketsSheet.getRange(newCUst,3).setValue(address)
      } 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Kin, thank you for your suggested code but unfortunately this is not what I require. I will try to explain.

Comment: I will try to explain. I do not want the "Customer" sheet to update. When I enter a customer code in the "Docket" sheet in column A, the script should find the match of the cell in column A in the "Customer" sheet and then copy over the data in columns B,C & D for that row. Then again when I enter the customer code in row 2 it will find and copy the data for that customer code from the "Customer" sheet. Any assistance with this will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You don't want to update the previous row but only the current row you enter?

Comment: Yes it's only the current row that I enter which is on the docketSheet, and when enter I want this to update the matching row data from the customerSheet. Thanks

Comment: Check my edited answer, it will only check and update last row in `Dockets sheet` now

Comment: Hi Kin, yes it is working great now, that's just what I was looking for! Thank you very much for your help. Excellent

Comment: Welcome, accept the answer if you find it useful :)